# Reducing curves in surfaces by Dehn twists

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Let $F$ be a compact, oriented surface. 
A Dehn move, $D_\beta$, on a simple closed curve (scc) $\alpha$ is a Dehn twist applied to $\alpha$ along a scc $\beta$ which intersects $\alpha$ once.

Is there a finite collection of scc's in $F$ such that every non-separating scc $\alpha$ in $F$ can be reduced to one of them by Dehn moves $D_\beta$ as above?

Can such reduction be made by $D_\beta^2$-moves?

Comment: It's been a while since I've thought about this topic, but isn't this question more or less implicitly answered in Lickorish's paper on the generators of the mapping class group?

Comment: I think I misread your question, although still not sure I understand it. You ask if there is a finite collection F st every α∈F can be reduced to one of them? What does that mean? α is already in F

Comment: @Paul: First of all, F is my surface :-). I edited the question slightly, which perhaps will help.

Comment: Okay, that is why I misinterpreted it(skipped the first part and thought it was the $F$inite collection). $F$ is a strange name for a surface :)

Comment: It is unclear what exactly your question means: Are you allowed to compose Dehn moves? Or do you mean that you are allowed to use only one Dehn move along a loop $\beta$ depending on $\alpha$? (In the latter case, the answer is negative because the diameter of the curve complex is infinite.)

Comment: @PaulPlummer: $F$ is a perfectly natural name for a surface if one's native language is German.

Comment: You are allowed to compose the moves D_beta, each for arbitrary beta intersecting the curve you apply it to once,